# How does Dimensional Storage interact with destroyed Techno-Organic weapons?

Tags: mekton

According to the rules for Techno-Organics (MZP P.80):

> Because Techno-Organic mecha, like any other living thing, feel pain, they suffer a -1 penalty on all actions for each system (excluding armor plating) that is *completely* destroyed.

But the rules for Dimensional Storage (MZP P.91) say the following:

> Dimensionally Stored equipment, when "stowed" in its pocket dimension, is completely inaccessible by anyone/anything other than the mecha to which it belongs.

So I am wondering, does a Techno-Organic weapon that has been completely destroyed and has been stowed away using Dimensional Storage still infer its penalty in its stored state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book doesn't provide an answer to that, so it would be the storyteller's call.

I would rule that as either one of:

- Techno-Organic mecha are, well, organic. Living. Their systems are grown, not bolted, and can't be made detachable as Dimensional Storage would require. **Dimensional Storage is just not applicable.**
- Dimensionally Stored system should be, well, present to be stored away. When the -1 penalty is in action, the system in question is completely destroyed in a traumatical fashion, and **you can't store away nothing**. Well, you can, but that doesn't change anything - the system in question is still completely destroyed, which is painful.

The first ruling appeals more to me, and goes more in line with the Dimensional Storage description (*emphasis mine*):

> With this Stupid Mekton Trick, your mecha has instant access to any *hand-held weapon and/or external device* (such as Command Armor, Combiner mecha, etc) which was designated as being Dimensionally Stored at the time the mecha was created.

As a compromise, I would allow Dimensional Storage of *some* systems (a really, really, anime-grade big sword, for example), with the condition of them not being organic.